# How to use HTML Image Button and PHP?

Tags: php, html

Okay, so here's the scenario. I have a simple HTML page:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="submit.php" method="get">
        <input type="image" src="btn_getStarted.png" name="getStarted" value="btnBasic1" alt="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Along with the submit.php page:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['getStarted'])) {
        echo "GOOD";
    }
    else {
        echo "BAD";
    }
?>
```

When submitting the form, I wold expect to be able to retrieve the value of `getStarted`, but that is not the case in IE.

Here are the URL's that are submitted:

**Firefox:** `http://localhost/submit.php?getStarted.x=57&getStarted.y=11&getStarted=btnBasic1`
**IE8:** `http://localhost/submit.php?getStarted.x=50&getStarted.y=21`
**IE6:** `http://localhost/submit.php?getStarted.x=67&getStarted.y=14`

I'm not really sure why IE is not receiving the `btnGetStarted` name from the input.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have IE to test, but perhaps look at adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the form element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. That's just how IE works. The .x and .y are the coordinates on the image that you clicked. You can use an image as an image map that way.

To do what you want, I recommend checking whether a different input variable has been set on your submit.php. You can add a hidden field especially for this, or use another input from your form.

Comment: Okay, so this is just a weird IE thing? I was unsure if it was something that I was doing.

Comment: No, not you. Just one of the fun browser incompatibilities we all get to deal with.

Answer (score 7):

The input is sent through as the x and y coordinates that were clicked on.

Since "." isn't a valid identifier character in PHP it's converted to "_" (this preserves compatability with register_globals).

So you need to check for `$_GET['getStarted_x']`

Comment: Thanks Greg.  Rather than checking whether the form was submitted (by checking 'getStarted_x', I was wanting to retrieve the value of the button (getStarted), which is passed in Firefox, but no IE. Is this just an IE thing?

Comment: IE and others (older ones at least).

Answer (score 2):

After all, you apparently just want a button with a background image, not a button with an image map. In this case replace `type="image"` by `type="submit"` and use CSS to style it with a background image.

Comment: I would recommend this solution. Alternatively, you can use `button` and decorate it by placing an `img` tag in it and/or using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those lovely IE "features".

You can't collect a value of a posted input image.

If you really want to get the posted value use a `<button>` element with an image inside. Else just check for the existence of the x or y value

Comment: Well, I thought about trying that, but in IE, the URL will be: http://localhost/submit.php?getStarted=%3CIMG+alt%3D%22Get+Started+Button%22+src%3D%22btn_getStarted.png%22%3E

Answer (score -3):

Your value tag is set to "btnBasic1", so IE passes that as the value for getStarted.

Comment: Well, apparently *not* (according to the OP).

Comment: But, as you can see from the above URL's, "btnBasic1" isn't passed in IE.